# An electronic cigarette company advertises that its disposable $1$ ml capacity ecigs each contain $18$ mg of nicotine.

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

An electronic cigarette company advertises that its disposable $1$ ml capacity ecigs each contain $18$ mg of nicotine. In fact, the amount of nicotine is normally distributed with mean $19$ mg and standard deviation $0.6$ mg.

$i)$ find the probability that the amount of nicotine in a randomly selected ecigs is between $18.5$ mg and $20.0$ mg.

$ii)$ The trading standard authority informs the company that, over a long period of time, at least $95$% of its ecigs should contain at least $18$ mg of nicotine. Keeping the original standard deviation, determine the smallest permissible mean content that ensures this is satisfied .

**My Working:**

$i)$

Let $X$ represent the amount of nicotine in a randomly selected ecig then

$$Pr(18.5<X<20)=Pr(\frac{18.5-19}{0.6}<X<\frac{20-19}{0.6})=Pr(-0.833<Z<1.666)=\Phi(1.666)-\Phi(-0.8666)=\Phi(1.666)-(1-\Phi(0.866))$$.

Where $Z$ is the standard normal random variable.

$ii)$ As for this part I don't have a clue where to begin. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working is fine!

> As for this part I don't have a clue where to begin. Any help will be appreciated

this is what they are asking you to calculate

$$\mathbb{P}[X\geq 18]\geq 0.95$$

$$\mathbb{P}\left[Z\geq \frac{18-\mu}{0.6}\right]\geq 0.95$$

Is this enough for you to conlcude that $\mu\geq 18.99$?

---

The gaussian CDF is noted by $\Phi$ while $\phi$ is its density. I edited you question.

Comment: Can we say the smallest possible value of $\mu$ will be $19$ since its given in the question,  or simply $\mu\geq 19$?

Comment: Also there is last part to this question I haven't posted here. I thought I will solve it but it similar to part $b$ and is causing confusion. The statement is: If over long period, more than $2.5$% of ecigs contain more than the EU legal limit of $20$ mg of nicotine, then find largest standard deviation value, keeping mean content at $19$ mg. My working goes similar to part $b$ of yours as: $Pr(X\geq 20)\geq 0.025=Pr(Z\geq \frac{20-19}{\sigma})\geq 0.025$. Is my working Okay so far. If yes then how do I conclude the the value of $\sigma$ from here.?

Comment: @Ameer786 : Yes, for the first question the correct result is "the smallest permissible mean is 19 mg", in fact I wrote $\mu\geq 19$ which is the same result.

As per the further question there is a typo in the exercise because what you are calculating is the "smallest permissible st dev"; in fact the more it is large, the more $P(X>20)$ increases, given a fixed mean.

Thus you can calculate, as in the previous case

$$\mathbb{P}[X>20|\mu=19]>2.5\%$$

$$\mathbb{P}\left[Z<\frac{20-19}{\sigma}\right]<97.5\%$$

$$\frac{1}{\sigma}<1.96\rightarrow\sigma \geq 0.510213...$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, we can use the inverse of $\Phi(x)$ which is called the confidence level.

The one-sided $95 \%$ confidence level is $z = -1.64485$ (check your textbook or use a GDC / online tool), so $18 = \mu - z \sigma$ where $\mu$ is the mean.

Comment: sorry but if $z=-1.64$ I think it is $18=\mu-z \sigma$